# Should I use a dictionary for membership testing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-complexity

Suppose I have two lists A, B such that A is a subset of B. If I were to parse through the points of B and each time I want to test if an element is a member of A, would representing A as a dictionary be better than as a list? I ask because I am under the impression that dictionaries have worst case lookup time O(1), whereas for arrays it is O(n).

That is, which of the following would be more efficient in terms of time complexity?

```
# Code 1
A = [1, 2, 3]
B = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3]

for i in B:
    if i in A:
        print (i)
    else:
        print (-1)
```

```
# Code 2
A = [1, 2, 3]
B = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3]

A_dict = {}
for i in A:
    A_dict[i] = 0

for i in B:
    if i in A_dict:
        print (i)
    else:
        print (-1)
```

It seems that if what I said about time complexities above is true, then the first code has complexity O(|B| x |A|), whereas the second has complexity O(|B|). Is this correct?

Comment: `I am under the impression that dictionaries have worst case lookup time O(1), whereas for arrays it is O(n).` Correct. (except certain edge cases, so, on amortized worst case O(1) lookup time is better) Also, `sets` have an O(1) lookup as well, so if you don't need key-value pairs, a `set` makes more sense than dicts

Comment: you should use `sets` for membership testing! That is the optimized object type for membership

Comment: Also, your 2nd code is very weird and roundabout way of checking if the items are present. you can use `in` for checking membership even in dicts as well.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh ah right. Thank you both very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) for that. They have O(1) lookup, like dicts, but they aren't key-value pairs.

Your code would then look like this:

```py
A = [1, 2, 3]
B = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3]

A_set = set(A)

for i in B:
    if i in A_set:
        print (i)
    else:
        print (-1)
```

or:

```py
A = {1, 2, 3}
...
```